# An unnset-variable default value?

Tags: php, variables

alot of time in programming the value of variables are passed through url parameters, 
in php;

```
if (isset($_GET['var'])) {$var = $_GET['var'];}
```

But if that does not execute, we will have an *unset variable*, in which may cause errors in the remaining of the code, i usually set the variable to '' or false;

```
else {$var = '';}
```

I was wondering what are the best practices, and why : )

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function

```
function get($name, $default = "") {
   return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : $default;
}
```

Comment: +1 I'm a big fan of creating small functions like this that reduce code size and increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

I favour using the [?: ternary operator](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
$var = isset($_GET['var'])) ? $_GET['var'] : 0;
```

but you can often combine this with code to sanitize your inputs too, e.g. if you're expecting a purely numeric argument:

```
$var = isset($_GET['var'])) ? intval($_GET['var']) : 0;
```